# My heap program does not work with large arrays

Tags: c++, queue, heap

Suppose you are trying to bind many books together.
The books may consist of a different number of pages. For example, Book A can have 12 pages and Book B can have 500 pages. 
Each time you bind two books together the total effort to perform the binding is equal to the number of pages in both books. For example, Binding Book A and Book B will require 512 units of effort. 
Write a program that takes in one line of input.
Your program must output the minimum units of effort required to bind all the books together.

Input:  100,12,6,40
Output: 234

NB: The best way to bind these books is to firstly bind 12 with 6 which costs 18 units of effort. We now have books of sizes {100, 18, 40}. We then can bind 18 and 40, which costs 58 units of effort. We now have books of sizes {100, 58}. And finally we bind 100 and 58 which requires 158 units of effort. Thus we required 18+58+158 = 234 units of effort.

I have a working program using heap and priority queue but this program does not work with large arrays such as Input: 187,65,13,4,5,89,13,55,4,99,544.
The correct answer is 2480 but my program gets 2546.
This is how the program should get 2480:

[How to get 2480](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQpMw.jpg)

This is my code:

```
int conStrToInt(string str) 
{
int res = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    res = res * 10 + (str[i]-48);
}
return res;
 }

 int main() {
 string in;
 cin >> in;
 stringstream ss(in);
 string elem;

priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int> > pq;
while(getline(ss, elem, ',')) {
    int temp = conStrToInt(elem);
    pq.push(temp);
}
long long res = 0;
long long a = pq.top();
pq.pop();

if(pq.empty()) {
    cout << 0 << endl;
    return 0;
}
int b = pq.top();
pq.pop();
while(!pq.empty()) {
    res += (a + b);
    a = a + b;
    b = pq.top();
    pq.pop();
}
res += (a+b);
cout << res << endl;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Your code seems to assume that `a+b` will always be the smallest number in the pqueue. This is not so for {2,3,4,4,6} , for example. You should rather insert `a+b` into the pqueue and fetch the next two smallest numbers from the queue.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please show me how to do this? Its my first time using heaps and queues

Answer (score 2):

Here is a rewritten `main`. It pushes the new number back onto the heap. If the heap size is reduced to 1 (ie the heap is empty after one pop) the loop stops.

```
int main() {
    string in;
    cin >> in;
    stringstream ss(in);
    string elem;

    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int> > pq;
    while(getline(ss, elem, ',')) {
        int temp = conStrToInt(elem);
        pq.push(temp);
    }

    if(pq.empty()) {
        cout << 0 << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    long long res = 0;
    while (true) {
        long long a = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        if (pq.empty()) {
            break;
        }
        long long b = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        res += a + b;
        pq.push(a+b);
    }

    cout << res << endl;
    return 0;

}
```